# How do I print out input KerasTensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the following code to train a NN in Keras using my own custom loss function. However, I don't really know what input is (it has the type KerasTensor). How can I print out its value? I need to access the training data point fed as an input to the networtk (e.g. [1,2,3,4]), its true label (e.g. [1]) and its predicted label (e.g. [-1]). How can I achieve this?

```
    def custom_loss(input):

        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            return ...
        return loss

    def custom_model():
        input = Input(shape=(16,))
        x = Dense(8, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='linear')(i)
        output = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear')(x)
        model = Model(input, output)
        model.compile(loss=custom_loss(input), optimizer='adam')
        return model
```

Also, small side question: why do we always specify the number of neurons in a layer by shape=(16,) and not simply by shape = 16? Does this make a difference? Also, what is the logical reason for using the first notation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the question is not exactly clear since we don't know when you want it to be printed out. Nonetheless to print a value during the fit you can always use a callback, that will be activated during the training : [link to doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback)

```py
class PrintingCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self, train_data):
        self.train_data_x, self.train_data_y = train_data

  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        for index in range(len(self.train_data_x)):
            input_value = self.train_data_x[index]
            label = self.train_data_y[index]
            predicted = self.model.predict(np.expand_dims(input_value, axis=0))
            print("input value : {}, real label : {}, predicted : {}".format(input_value, label, predicted))
```

And then on the fit you give the callback,

```py
x_train = np.zeros((150, 16))
y_train = np.zeros((150, 1))
...

model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    ...
    callbacks=[PrintingCallback((x_train,
    y_train))],
)
```

and during the fit you will have printed the input value, true label and predicted at the end of each batch.

Keep in mind that you could also use Tensorboard to print those value and get it afterwards using a writer and printing scalars to the dashboard : https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this, however I ot the following error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad I though batch was the batch value but it's only the index, I change my answer, you may need to tweak your data into the network, depending on your case, that's why I added a np.expand_dims